# unable to change git branch to main branch

Tags: git, github

```
$ git reflog

/e/eli/flicki ((33bff44...))

33bff44 (HEAD) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to 33bff443646f2097e07e1067051468990ee16487
b2ed2b7 (origin/main) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to b2ed2b7277f5e8d6e61bd585f96d763e032e68a9
33bff44 (HEAD) HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to 33bff443646f2097e07e1067051468990ee16487
7a18198 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to 7a181984a0d6ec9db281d8d1f8e61b91767f5b55
33bff44 (HEAD) HEAD@{4}: commit: new feature
b2ed2b7 (origin/main) HEAD@{5}: rebase (start): checkout b2ed2b7277f5e8d6e61bd585f96d763e032e68a9
f4ca5b4 (main) HEAD@{6}: commit: added analytic page and timestamp table and filter message functionality

$ git branch
* (no branch)
  main
```

I have made my last commit directly to GitHub file editor, after 10 days I have committed again, but
from my local computer, after pushing to repo it throws an error, and then I used `git pull rebase origin main` and then used `rm -rf .git/rebase-merge` command after that I am lost and stuck and cannot switch to `main` branch. Please guide me to get to `main` branch as you can above see /e/eli/flicki ((33bff44...)) is stuck

[Edit by @torek: specifically, `git checkout main` produces

```
error: cannot stat 'lib/flicki_web/templates/analytic': Permission denied
```

[see comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68326923/unable-to-change-git-branch-to-main-branch#comment120758108_68326923).]

Comment: that `rm -rf` sounds like it could have been a bad idea. There is a way to use git commands to abort the rebase (`git rebase --abort)` when you get confused.

Comment: In your current commit, is everything how you want it to be? Or are some files wrong, some history other than you wanted, ... ? Because if everything is fine, you could create a new branch from the current commit (`git checkout -b newbranch`) and then merge that into `main`

Comment: what is significance of no  branch? also this is my first encounter to rebase so it has badly messed up my code also

Comment: It's hard to tell where your sentences begin and end, which makes your question difficult or impossible to comprehend. Can you [edit] your question to add the missing punctuation, please?

Comment: @sameer07 I think what happened is that you started a rebase, had some conflicts or did not finish it otherwise, and then did the `rm`, making weird things happen. Now your commit still exists, but is not on the branch. (Think of a branch as a pointer to the latest commit on it)

Comment: What about just checking out main?

Comment: Why can't you switch back to main? `git checkout main`? (perhaps you need to undo all local, uncommitted changes first)

Comment: `error: cannot stat 'lib/flicki_web/templates/analytic': Permission denied`
whenever I try to switch to main or merge to main i an getting above error, I don't know but somehow two of my files are unable to save whenever I try to save it, and i am using sublime

Comment: @sameer07 check permission of the file and its parent directories. Make sure no other process is preventing the file from being created or deleted (a problem especially on windows). Make sure your user has appropriate permissions. You can try to manually delete the file and folder, then restore from a commit

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you have everything you want either in the commit you made or on `origin`, then I would do something like this:

first git fetch so you have a local copy of everything on github

```
git fetch
```

if you have `gitk` which you usually do you can see a picture of all the branches on github and locally like this

```
gitk --all &
```

but if I understand the situation correctly,

```
git reset --hard # get rid of anything local that is going on
git checkout main # go back to main branch
git reset --hard 33bff44 # move your current files and branch to the new feature
```

(the last command might not be necessary, but since we know which commit we want, it won't hurt.  But if you want you can find out if it is necessary before doing it like this `git rev-parse HEAD`.  That will tell you if main is already on that commit, or if you changed it somehow.)

now I think you should be where you were where you started.  gitk should show something like

```
common-base --- commit you made on github (origin/main)
            \-- commit you made locally (main)
```

and then I would not use `git pull`.  I would just convert my local branch into one with everything you on github, plus the commit you have locally like this:

```
git rebase origin/main
```

now if that worked because there are no conflicts, you will be one commit ahead of github, and you can just push your change like you tried to before

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have several problems going on, and given the issues in the question itself, it's hard to be sure about any exact order of things to do to go about fixing them.  The problems include:

- The `permission denied` error: this implies that you may have run some operations as the super-user (`sudo command`, for instance).  You may need to change the ownership of these files back to yourself, so that you can work on / with them.  But we can't see precisely what the problem is, so I cannot say precisely how to fix it either.
- The `rm -rf .git/rebase-merge`: This made Git "forget" that you were in the middle of an incomplete rebase.  *You were and are still in the middle of this incomplete rebase*, but it's now impossible to make Git take you out of it normally, because you destroyed the information Git needs to do that.

I think the most promising way to get out of this problem is to fix the permissions issue first.  You will then be able to use `git checkout main`, which will get you out of the incomplete rebase more or less as if you had used `git rebase --abort`.  You can then start over.

Alternatively, you can completely abandon this clone (and any commits you made in this clone that are not already on GitHub).  That's not a *very good* solution, of course.  If you can fix the permissions issue, [Alex028502's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68327491/1256452) may be a better way to proceed.